# Activity view for Android

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, uiactivityviewcontroller

Currently I am building an app and in IOS the users get the choice, what to do with the content. The most important activities are 'Copy' and 'WhatsApp'. Options are given through the activity viewcontroller as seen in the example image below:

[image: UIActivity ViewController]

This is build in Xamarin so the activity view controller is called through an IOS dependency. I am not very familiar with Android and I was wondering if android has something comparable?

(And what is it called, I could not find any hits on google with android and activity view)

---

If it exists and I know how it is called, I can use it for android in the Android dependency.

Comment: I believe you'll want to get somewhat familiar with [the official Android documentation on how to share content with other apps](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send) ;)

Comment: @MartinMarconcini Thank you! Seems like the thing I was looking for. But if you do not know the name, you can search for a long time hehe.. Can you add this as a regular answer? not as a comment.

Comment: Certainly; there you have it. Good luck and don't hesitate to post other questions with more specific issues if you have them. (Hopefully not!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Android, you can "talk" to other apps even if you don't know them, simply by telling the OS, "Hey, I have this data type, that I want to share, can you show the user apps and actions that can handle it so he/she can decide?"

They are called `Intents` (get it? :p)

Anyway, there's basically the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send) about how to do this. So I suggest you refer back to it (and other readers of the future) for things may change between releases.

The short answer is: fire an intent indicating what you want to share, and let Android do its thing.